# Alias that SSH into a VM and Execute a Script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, alias

In my `~/.bash_profile` on my Mac, I created an alias:

`alias ssh_retish='ssh -Y root@172.19.242.35; cd /root/Bitbucket_DTH; ./dth -k MDU_SSC_014 -p pink1 -z'`

---

## Goal

is to run that alias to :

- ssh into a machine (I've already added my pub key in the authorized file)
- go to a certain directory `cd /root/Bitbucket_DTH;`
- execute a script `./dth -k MDU_SSC_014 -p pink1 -z`

Can someone please fill in what I miss here ?

---

## Result

After running this alias `ssh_retish` on a freshly new terminal tab, I kept landing on my `/root` and nothing is executed.

```
Last login: Thu Sep  1 15:34:29 2016 from macbookpro
[root@cl-dth ~]# pwd
/root
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to do

```
alias ssh_retish='ssh -Y root@172.19.242.35 "cd /root/Bitbucket_DTH; ./dth -k MDU_SSC_014 -p pink1 -z"'
```

Execute the command and the change directory on the remote server, not on your local computer.